# Get the "active" class name of a dynamic class in vue

Tags: javascript, html, class, vue.js

I have this code for a card in vue:

```
<div  id="card" class="card" :class="{'border-danger': alertaCPU }" style="max-width: 18rem;">
```

I create 6 elements with this template and the border becomes red in the cases that the value gets over a limit. This is the code for the function:

```
  alertaCPU: function() {
        if (this.valor > this.limite ) {
          this.audio.play();
          console.log("Playingg");

          return true;
        }
        return false;

      }
```

I try to get the name of the class of the different elements :

```
document.getElementById("card").className
```

And all the time it returns all the name of the class without the dynamic condition.

```
 card border-danger
```

Is possible to get the className that is been used at this moment?

Comment: Please reproduce the issue on js fiddle and post the link here

Answer (score 0):

For this code `:class="{'border-danger': alertaCPU }"`, class condition always returns **true**; `alertaCPU` is always **truthy value** since it is a function.

Vue.js class syntax expects a class object to be of the following type:

```
{ 'class-name': truthyValue }
```

Here you are just passing a function name which is always a **truthy value**. You must covert this function to **getter** like following:

```
computed: {
    alertaCPU: function() {
        if (this.valor > this.limite ) {
        this.audio.play();
        console.log("Playingg");

        return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

Second, your class `"card"` is statically bound to your DOM element and will always exists irrespective of the dynamically added class. What you can do here is to Regular Expression or `.classList` instead of `.className` property like:

```
document.getElementById("card").classList;
```

**classList** is basically an array of all the classes applied to that element. Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).